# QSyntaxHighlighter highlight ascii?

Tags: c++, qt, syntax-highlighting

How can I get the QSyntaxHighlighter to syntax highlight ascii characters like @ or #? This is my current code:

```
Highlighter::Highlighter(QTextDocument *parent)
    : QSyntaxHighlighter(parent)
{
HighlightingRule rule;
keywordFormat.setForeground(Qt::darkBlue);
keywordFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);
QStringList keywordPatterns;
keywordPatterns << "\\bchar\\b" << "\\bclass\\b" << "\\bconst\\b"
        << "\\bdouble\\b" << "\\benum\\b" << "\\bexplicit\\b"
        << "\\bfriend\\b" << "\\binline\\b" << "\\bint\\b"
        << "\\blong\\b" << "\\bnamespace\\b" << "\\boperator\\b"
        << "\\bprivate\\b" << "\\bprotected\\b" << "\\bpublic\\b"
        << "\\bshort\\b" << "\\bsignals\\b" << "\\bsigned\\b"
        << "\\bslots\\b" << "\\bstatic\\b" << "\\bstruct\\b"
        << "\\btemplate\\b" << "\\btypedef\\b" << "\\btypename\\b"
        << "\\bunion\\b" << "\\bunsigned\\b" << "\\bvirtual\\b"
        << "\\bvoid\\b" << "\\bvolatile\\b" << "\\b@implementation\\b";
foreach (QString pattern, keywordPatterns) {
    rule.pattern = QRegExp(pattern);
    rule.format = keywordFormat;
    highlightingRules.append(rule);
}

classFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);
classFormat.setForeground(Qt::darkMagenta);
rule.pattern = QRegExp("\\bQ[@-A-Za-z]+\\b");
rule.format = classFormat;
highlightingRules.append(rule);

singleLineCommentFormat.setForeground(Qt::red);
rule.pattern = QRegExp("//[^\n]*");
rule.format = singleLineCommentFormat;
highlightingRules.append(rule);

multiLineCommentFormat.setForeground(Qt::red);

quotationFormat.setForeground(Qt::darkGreen);
rule.pattern = QRegExp("\".*\"");
rule.format = quotationFormat;
highlightingRules.append(rule);

functionFormat.setFontItalic(true);
functionFormat.setForeground(Qt::blue);
rule.pattern = QRegExp("\\b[A-Za-z0-9_]+(?=\\()");
rule.format = functionFormat;
highlightingRules.append(rule);

commentStartExpression = QRegExp("/\\*");
commentEndExpression = QRegExp("\\*/");
}
```

How would I get it to highlight @implementation or #include or #ifndef? I was thinking of changing the Regex.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at http://ariya.blogspot.com/2010/09/minimalistic-javascript-editing-widget.html which I wrote some time ago. Your way of doing highlighting will result in complicated, hard-to-maintain, and slow code.